# Вызов переопределенной функции

Tags: функции, классы, c++

Есть цикл, в ходе которого вызывается функция класса `A - foo()`, Далее я переопределяю эту функцию в производном классе B.

```
class A {
    virtual void foo() { }
};

class B : A {
    virtual void foo() { }
};
```

Однако функция в классе B не вызывается совсем, хотя в свое время функция foo() класса A вызывается как нужно. Возможно ли воссоздать так, чтобы вызов функции класса A проходил по всем ее потомкам с этой же функцией, но переопределенной?

**[update больше кода]**

```
class Manager {
public:
    Manager();
    virtual ~Manager();

    //code code code

    //Эта функция вызывается в главном цикле
    static void update() {
        for(int i=0; i < objArray.size(); i++) {
            BaseObject obj = objArray[i];

            obj.update();
        }
    }

private:
    static std::vector<BaseObject> objArray;
};

class BaseObject {
    //code code code
    //при инициализации добавляем в objArray

    //Функция, которую переопеределяем в потомках
    virtual void update() {

    }
};

class ChildObject : BaseObject {
    //code code code
    //производим инициализацию

    //Переопределяем функцию
    virtual void update() {
        //code code code
        //собственно, функция которая должна вызываться каждый проход цикла,
        //однако, этого не происходит
    }
};
```

Comment: предоставьте чуточку больше кода, что бы его можно было скомпилировать и посмотреть, что именно там не так работает.

Comment: чуточку больше есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда объекты добавляются в вектор, то происходит копирование. А так как вектор хранит объекты известного типа, то и копироваться они будут в него. При таком копировании информация о типе будет утеряна. Плюс, в коде есть ещё одно копирование - собственно там, где вызывается функция update.

Кода конечно приложили маловато, поэтому мне пришлось додумать его, что бы он работал и поправить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class BaseObject {
    //code code code
    //при инициализации добавляем в objArray
public:
    //Функция, которую переопеределяем в потомках
    virtual void update() {
            // это вывод, что бы понимать, что вызвалось
        cout << "base update\n";
    }
};

class ChildObject : public BaseObject {
    //code code code
    //производим инициализацию
public:
    //Переопределяем функцию
    virtual void update() {
        //code code code
        //собственно, функция которая должна вызываться каждый проход цикла,
        //однако, этого не происходит
        cout << "child update\n";
    }
};

class Manager {
public:
    Manager();
    virtual ~Manager();

    //code code code

    //Эта функция вызывается в главном цикле
    static void update() {
        for(size_t i=0; i < objArray.size(); i++) {
            BaseObject * obj = objArray[i];

            obj->update();

        }
    }
    static void push(BaseObject* ob) {
        Manager::objArray.push_back(ob);
    }
private:
    static std::vector<BaseObject*> objArray;
};
std::vector<BaseObject*> Manager::objArray;

int main() {
    // это инициализация - помещаем два объекта разного типа.
    // соответственно должны увидеть две разные строки в консоли.
    Manager::push(new BaseObject());
    Manager::push(new ChildObject());
    // дергаем метод обновления.
    Manager::update();
    // тут нужно добавить ещё очистку вектора, что бы не было утечек.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь все работает.